# Chevron Down icon not displaying in Semantic Dropdown

Tags: css, asp.net, semantic-ui

I have a requirement to change the semantic UI dropdown icon to Chevron Down ('\f078')from Caret Down('\f0d7').

I did follow the suggestion in the following JSFiddle but it did not work for me. https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/5104

I have uploaded my sample code in the jSFiddle
    https://jsfiddle.net/6jgqxc1a/4/

```
.ui.dropdown > .dropdown.icon:before {
    content: '\f0d7';
}
```

It is just a sample code. Dropdown may not work but you can change the icon values at line number 98.
If I change the values to Caret Up('\f0d8'), Left('\f0d9') and right('\f0da') then it works. 
However, if update the value to ('\f078') it just shows a rectangle. I am not sure if I have been doing anything wrong here.

Any input or suggestion is more than welcome

Comment: Please include code in the question itself, not a link to a jsfiddle, or as in this case, a github repository. Better still use the `<>` button in the editor to provide a [MCVE] . Make it as easy as possible for us to help you.

Comment: You haven't linked to a JSFiddle; you've linked to a closed GitHub issue. Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your feedback. I have updated the question to give more details. Hope it conveys my problem clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just use svg for the content?:

https://jsfiddle.net/6ggxj6f1/

```
    .ui.dropdown > .dropdown.icon:before {
        content: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='15' height='21' fill='Red' stroke='none'><path d='M0,0 6,18 L12,0 L0,0 Z'></path></svg>");
}
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, it sounds good. I will try it out with my own svg image.
Thank you very much.